# Getting SignalR working with Angular 5 running in dot net framework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, signalr

I am currently attempting to get SignalR working using the Dot Net Core Angular template available within Visual Studio Professional.  I have a lot of legacy code that I need to keep working, so I have selected .NET Framework 4.6.1.

[image: Selecting .NET Framework as a choice when building a dot net core 2 Angular app]

I've had a play around with the various available packages in nuget but have been unable to successfully install SignalR. That is, the package installs (assuming I have the right one) but inside the Startup.cs file, I don't seem to be able to reference UseSignalR etc.

I would think that it *should* be able to be done, because I am targeting dot net framework 4.6.1. Is this possible, and if so, what is the correct approach/package for getting this working?

Answer (score 0):

Using of Visual Studio Templates are not the best solution in each case. I suggest you to wire up the signalr by yourself. In the case you go this way you will learn how your applications works in detail and you will be faster at searching of errors.

1. Install required packages:

   install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
2. Change your startup

   public class Startup {

   ```
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
     // Add CORS if required 
     app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);          
     // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here  
     app.MapSignalR();
     }
   ```

   }
3. Do the required client stuff.
   Out of your question it is not clear which version of angular you are using. 
   Maybe https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub is a solution for you

Comment: In my configure, I was able to add app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin()); but not the Cors policy you specified. There's still no MapSignalR or UseSignalR, even though it successfully installed AspNet.SignalR 2.2.3. I have included using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR; in the Startup.cs file. It's the default Startup.cs file for the template, not a generated Owin Startup class. Kind of feels wrong if it needs two different startups!

Comment: The Angular version is 4.2.5. I've chosen to get SignalR working out of the box with that template because that's what the original application is using, and I don't want to change it at this stage for legacy reasons.

Comment: @tone You have to do this by yourself: app.MapSignalR(); inside your startup. Take a look hereee: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server